# accidentally deleted yum.repos.d/ fedora 24

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I accidentally ran this command:

`sudo rm -r /etc/yum.repos.d/`

How do I recover the contents of this folder / find out what they were ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should checkout this post on the Fedora form. https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/35074/restore-fedora-official-repository-files/

In places of the URL where you see 20 I would replace with 24.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot recover this directory or its contents unless you have a backup.

However, unless you have made modifications to the files in that directory (which are your Yum repository specifications), you should be able to retreive the files as they were from another Fedora system of the same version. If there were custom modifications or additional files added, and you don't have a backup, then they are gone forever.